# Is it possible to put a "Clickable Link" inside of a Systray Notification Bubble?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Not much to add to this.  Have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are two options though. The simplest is to just use the click event of the balloon to trigger the event you require. The more complicated one is to create a custom balloon within which you can present a link.

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx for an example of how this could be accomplished.